# How to increment a large number as a string as if it were an integer?

Tags: c#, string, f#

I've been trying to think of ways to do it, I can't just convert the string to an int. It's too long to be an int, that's the reason I need to do this. I can do it for single digits, but as soon as I want to add say 10 or 20 I'm not sure how to change my code to allow that. If I increase the loop it will increase the length of the string and that wouldn't be treating it as an actual number. The reason I include two languages is because I will accept C# or F# code in an answer.

```
open System

type String with
    member this.Last() =
        this.[this.Length - 1]

let mutable s = "1234567890" // the numbers I will use are a lot bigger than this.

for i in 0 .. 9 do // 9 is max before it increases the length of the string.
    printfn "%s" s

    let last = (s.Last().ToString() |> int) + 1

    s <- s.[0 .. s.Length - 2] + last.ToString()

Console.Read() |> ignore
```

Comment: What's wrong with [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: The numbers I will use will be over 16 digits in length sometimes, I tried and it's too big for a bigint.

Comment: OK, It's incorrect. You should go and read about BigInteger. BTW 16 digits is small enough to fit even in `long`.

Comment: I tried ```let n = BigInteger(10000000000)``` with System.Numerics and it says the number is outside the allowable range for 32-bit signed integers. When I add type annotations for Int64 it tells me it's expecting Int64 but here is int. What am I missing?

Comment: "The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds. " - MSDN

Comment: Alanay you're missing the fact that the compiler will try and make an int out of your 10000000000 before it is passed to bigint. I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8#instantiating-a-biginteger-object -"if th value you have is too large for a built in type ..."

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks, that did help. I know how to use them now.

Comment: Incidentally, decimals go up to around 32 digits and may be easier to work with for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is any situation where using strings to represent numbers would be a good idea - you can use `BigInteger` to represent and work with large numbers and it supports all numerical operations, not just incrementing by one.

However, it is a fun problem, so here is one possible F# solution:

```
let incString (s:string) = 
  let rec loop acc carry i (s:string) =  
    match i, carry with 
    | -1, true -> System.String(Array.ofList ('1'::acc))
    | -1, false -> System.String(Array.ofList acc)
    | _ ->
      match s.[i], carry with 
      | '9', true -> loop ('0'::acc) true (i-1) s 
      | c, false -> loop (c::acc) false (i-1) s
      | c, true -> loop (char ((int c) + 1)::acc) false (i-1) s
  loop [] true (s.Length-1) s

incString "9899"
```

The inner `loop` function takes the following parameters:

- `acc` is an accumulator, used to collect digits of the new number (starting from the end)
- `carry` is a boolean flag that is `true` if we want to add `1` to the next number (this is initially `true` and then it is also `true` as long as the digits are `9` - because `9` will become `0` and we then need to add to the next digit in the string).
- `i` is the current index, starting from the last one
- `s` is the input string representing the original number.

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason I needed it is to scrape images from websites that are all numbers and increment for each image not just randomly change it. Usually 16+ digits. So this is very useful!

Comment: @Alanay You should really just use `BigInteger` - see the edit for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you reverse it into a list of chars
the try to increment the lowest digit,
if that doesnt work (its a 9), you set the lowest digit to '0' and recurse the tail

```
let inc: string -> string =
    let rec incRev: List<char> -> List<char> =             
        function
        | [] -> [ '1' ]
        | '9' :: cs -> '0' :: incRev cs
        | c :: cs -> char (int c + 1) :: cs
    fun s -> 
        s.ToCharArray() 
        |> Array.toList 
        |> List.rev
        |> incRev
        |> List.rev
        |> Array.ofList
        |> System.String
```

Answer (score 0):

another probably slightly more efficient answer (I prefer the previous one), but doesnt have all the reversing going on.
you fold from the back of the list of chars assembling an answer and passing the carry digit up to the end.

```
let inc2: string -> string =
    let incDigit : (char * (List<char> * char)) -> (List<char> * char) =
        function 
        | (c,(a,'0'))   -> (c :: a,'0')
        | ('9',(a,'1')) -> ('0' :: a,'1')
        | (c,(a,'1'))   -> ((char (int c + 1)) :: a,'0')            
    fun s -> 
        let result = 
            (s.ToCharArray() 
            |> Array.toList 
            |> List.foldBack (fun c state -> incDigit (c,state))) ([],'1')
        result
        |> fst
        |> if (snd result = '1') then (fun cs -> '1' :: cs) else id
        |> Array.ofList
        |> System.String
```

Comment: yeah, I agree...to be honest, I was just trying to find an excuse to use foldback