# Is there a way to generate all binary possibilities given a number N>=2,073,600 representing the size of the binary number?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary, combinations

For example:
N=3 would generate:

```
1- 0 0 0
2- 0 0 1
3- 0 1 0
4- 0 1 1
5- 1 0 0
6- 1 0 1
7- 1 1 0
8- 1 1 1
```

I need this to build a program that receives a real big matrix size (like 1920x1080) and starts to print a matrix based on the array (in this case of size 2,073,600) with all the zeros and ones updating as they are generated.

Comment: If you're saying that you want to generate all possible binary numbers for N=2073600, then let me point out that even N=64 is an impossibly large number for a typical desktop computer. If that's not what the last paragraph is saying, then the last paragraph needs some clarification.

Comment: It's exactly that. One approach I thought of was to transform the large number in a string, and implement the increment algorithm from scratch. The problem with this approach is that if the carry digit has to go too far from the beginning, the algorithm would have to go through a lot of characters to make the calculation, and would be really slow. I was hoping to find a better method here but this is the only possible way so far.

Comment: @IsaacReinaldo No algorithm running on personal computers will be able to iterate through 2^2073600 values, no matter how you build/represent them.

Comment: The idea of the program is to execute almost forever and see the results changing dynamically. I don't think it is necessary to iterate through 2^2073600 because it is possible to create an algorithm that just iterate through the 2073600 zeros and ones and check if it needs to be toggled or not (the incrementing big numbers in string algorithm does that, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839373/how-to-increment-a-large-number-as-a-string-as-if-it-were-an-integer) ). I just would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @IsaacReinaldo A typical frame rate nowadays is 120 fps. Which is to say that you can change the image on the screen 120 times in one second. That's about 4 billion images per year. If you have N=64, you would need to run the program for **4 billion years** just to see all of the possibilities **for an 8x8 region** in the middle of your 1920x1080 screen. So your statement that *"the program is to execute almost forever"* is a huge understatement. For 1920x1080, the program would still need to be running after the heat death of the universe.

Comment: That's right. The challenge is not to see the majority of images it would generate, but I thought it would be cool to find an algorithm that could start to generate those images (even though it would have a lot of black pixels) without exploding my computer haha. But I really don't know if it is possible. The best way I could think of was really unpractical. Also, after pondering it better, I don't think it is indeed interesting to find this algorithm just to watch a bunch of black pixels haha. Thank you!

Comment: I was able, however, to do it with just one pixel and see the changes, I think it is better to leave it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a loop from zero to 2 ^ size - 1, and each number in that range display it in base-2 format.

```js
const matrix = (size) => {
  const out = [];
  const max = Math.pow(2, size);
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    out.push(`${i + 1}: ${i.toString(2).padStart(size, '0')}`);
  }
  return out;
}

console.log(matrix(4));
```

Comment: I love this approach, the only problem is that it wouldn't handle 2^2,073,600 digits.

Comment: 2^2,073,600 = 6.295x10^624215

Comment: @IsaacReinaldo Use a `BigInt` then. But it's still a bad idea to build a number with that many digits.

Comment: The original problem is to build a program that have a display and generates all the possibilities of images that a display can produce. It would be doing it indefinitely and showing the results on a html page. If it could be executed for a lot (really a LOT) of time, it would show almost all the images our eyes could see. However, as we would only run it for a short amount of time, the idea is to see just some abstract and beautiful color formations.

Comment: @IsaacReinaldo You're better of generating some random images then. It would take an awful long time already to even fill the first row of pixels with some values, the remainder of the screen stays black. Also if you want color, that's actually `(256^3)^(1920*1080)` values (assuming 8 bit depth), not just `2^(1920*1080)`.

Comment: Yeah! You're completely right. About the '(256^3)^(1920*1080)', I asked just about '2^(1920*1080)' to simplify, in a way that if I could understand an algorithm that worked to '2^(1920*1080)', I would be able to derive some other to use on the '(256^3)^(1920*1080)', you know? But I think I really came to a dead end.

Comment: "Of size 2 million" was added much later than this answer.  Question is now unanswerable due to the universe not having enough particles for that kind of storage.